# Simple bouncing calculations going wrong

Tags: python, physics

im trying to learn python so that i can play around with mathematics. Ive been trying to implement a very simple simulation of a bouncing object with minimal physics but it does not seem to be working properly. The calculations should give me a wave pattern but for some reason the numbers keep decreasing. Is this some sort of math artifact that happens in Python? There is no reason for the numbers to be decreasing from my understanding since im only using very trivial arithmetics.

```
import sys, pygame

velocity = 0
acceleration = 0.1
ycord = 50

while 1:

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)

    velocity -= acceleration
    ycord += velocity

    if ycord <= 0:
    velocity *= -1

    print (ycord)
```

Comment: i do not have pygame. so i removed the pygame time clock and used `time.sleep` instead, and the code seemed to work just fine for me.

Comment: The problem is in your `if ycord <=0 :` condition: it happens sometimes that on the next iteration, due to rounding errors common with floats, `ycord` remains negative and `velocity` is multiplied by -1 again, keeping you under 0. You could set `ycord` to 0 when this condition is met, for example. That doesn't make the simulation perfect, but you are bouncing under the floor anyway...

Comment: Okay! thanks for the recommendations, ill try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the velocity is reversed only after the `ycord` has become negative.
To change this behaviour, you will have to calculate the velocity when the ycord reaches zero and change the sign.
Or simply, chose a better starting `ycord` so that the ball reaches exactly 0 and never goes into the negative range.
I think if you change your initial ycord to 52.8, you will see a difference.

In terms of physics, you are simulating a dampening effect, since the ball is losing energy in going from negative `ycord` to 0. So when the ycord becomes zero, it is starting with a lesser velocity than it did when it crossed zero.

Comment: Do you know of a way to simulate basic acceleration physics without those artifacts?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by artefacts. Can you clarify a bit more ?

Comment: A way to calculate acceleration and colision so that the numbers are accurate and i dont lose this velocity!

Comment: you can use equations of motions and make a strategy based on it, or as I said above ..choose a better starting **ycord**